# keep more specific row in grouped data (species over genus level, if available)

Tags: r, dplyr

I am searching for a solution I am stuck in. I am trying to clean up a data set with found species. However, some of them could only be described at genus level. Therefore, to avoid double counting those rows that have both available like a observation as "Genus spec." and "Genus X", e.g. calculating species number per plot and month. There are some cases where only "Genus spec." is available and no "Genus X", than I would like to not remove such rows but keep them in the group (plot, month) in the dataset. I read and thought, may be a key column could help, but I didn't get further. Any idea how to approach that, keep species level data of the same genus grouped by of plot and month if available but if not rather keep the genus level rows if no species level is available in that genus? (I would like to rather remove such unkown "genus spec." as species level gives me better information)

Here is an example data set, previous code and how the outcome should look like:

```
library(dplyr)
plot= c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2)
month= c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)
genus = c("a","a","a","b","c","d","a","a","a","b","c","d")
species = c(" a"," b"," spec."," b"," c"," d"," spec."," spec."," spec."," b"," c"," d")    prio = c(1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1)

veg_dummy_df = as.data.frame(cbind(plot,month,prio,genus,species))
#veg_dummy_df$genus_spec = do.call(paste, c(veg_dummy_df[c("genus","species")], sep = ""))
#veg_dummy_df$genus_prio = do.call(paste, c(veg_dummy_df[c("genus","prio")], sep = ""))
veg_dummy_df = veg_dummy_df %>% mutate(across(c(1:5), factor))

veg_dummy_df %>% group_by(plot,month)
#what am I missing here to get what I want?^^#
```

A tibble: 12 x 5
Groups:   plot, month [4]

plot  month prio  genus species
1 1     1     1     a     " a"
2 1     1     1     a     " b"
***3 1     1     2     a     " spec."*** #should be removed

4 2     1     1     b     " b"
5 2     1     1     c     " c"
6 2     1     1     d     " d"
7 1     2     2     a     " spec." #should be kept

8 1     2     2     a     " spec." #should be kept

9 1     2     2     a     " spec." #should be kept

10 2     2     1     b     " b"
11 2     2     1     c     " c"
12 2     2     1     d     " d"

I would be glad about help :) thanks a lot

Comment: Your question can be rather unclear for a non-expert in biological classification. In your example, why exactly should these rows be removed or kept? Is `prio` involved? (you don't talk about this one)